# Place text in plotting area of QML ChartView

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

How do I place text at specific (x,y) locations within the plotting area of a QML `ChartView` type?

For example, I would like to place text at the location `XYPoint{x: 1.3; Y: 5.8}`.

Comment: Check this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414937/how-to-add-a-rectangle-to-a-qml-chartview)