# How to add a rectangle to a QML ChartView?

Tags: qt, qml, qchartview

I want to put a number of rectangles as overlays to show regions of interest on a ChartView of ScatterSeries. However when I try to do this it is clearly using a different coordinate system to that of the ScatterSeries as it is drawn in a completely different place.

For example the following is intended to draw a rectangle that captures all of the ScatterSeries but it just draws a small green rectangle top left as shown in the screenshot.

```
        ChartView {
            id: view
            Layout.fillWidth : true
            Layout.fillHeight : true
            Rectangle {
                id: rec
                x: 30
                y: 50
                width: 40
                height: 10
                color: "green"
            }
            ScatterSeries{
                id: series
                XYPoint { x: 30; y: 50 }
                XYPoint { x: 50; y: 60 }
                XYPoint { x: 60; y: 50 }
                XYPoint { x: 70; y: 60 }
                axisX: ValueAxis {
                    min: 0
                    max: 100
                }
                axisY: ValueAxis {
                    min: 0
                    max: 100
                }
            }
```

[image]

The documentation suggests that the rectangle should use the coordinate system of the parent ChartView. I assume I actually want it to use the coordinate system of the ChartView scene. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To translate from the `ScatterSeries` coordinate system to pixel coordinates to place a child in `ChartView` use [mapToPosition(...)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html#mapToPosition-method):

```js
function updateRectangle() {
    var topLeftPoint = view.mapToPosition(Qt.point(30,60), series)
    var bottomRightPoint = view.mapToPosition(Qt.point(70,50), series)

    rec.x = topLeftPoint.x
    rec.y = topLeftPoint.y

    rec.width  = bottomRightPoint.x - topLeftPoint.x
    rec.height = bottomRightPoint.y - topLeftPoint.y
}
```

Where `series` is your `ScatterSeries` and `rec` is your `Rectangle`.

Invoke the update function whenever the chart points get recalculated (e.g. after creation and size changes).

See also related question [How to map QChart coordinate to QChartView point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919092/how-to-map-qchart-coordinate-to-qchartview-point)

Comment: That worked great. I have modified the example in the question so that the ids view, series and rec tie in with the parameters your answer to make it clearer.